# In a recipe, yogurt toughens potatoes but whipping cream does not

Tags: grilling

I have a favorite tried & true recipe that I simply call ‘foil potatoes’.  recipe link: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/048c56cc-1481-48b2-89e6-88e897da651a/b0c036a6448b07e0a486f77acf2111cb
This has been made multiple times with consistently good results.
A few weeks ago I decided to try substituting the same quantity of home-made  greek-style yogurt in place of the whipping cream.
They did not tenderize at all and although being fully cooked, were ‘crunchy’ and not desireable.

As an experiment yesterday, I did another batch with part of it done with the original recipe using whipping cream,, & the rest with yogurt.
All packets were done on the same grill side-by side with exactly the same time & temp.
The packets with whipping cream were done perfectly & again the ones with yogurt were tough.
My internet searches have not found any answers as to why this happened.
In addition to wanting to understand the science of this difference, can anyone suggest changes I can make to have this substitution work?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advise! Can you post the whole receipe? I can't access the receipe via the given link.

Comment: Without seeing the recipe (permissions issue - it is not a public doc) it is hard to know if something else is going on, but at a minimum, the water content in cream is significantly higher than in Greek-style (strained) yogurt. I suspect that a non-strained yogurt would probably have a similar result to your cream version. You can also "reconstitute" strained yogurt by mixing water or milk in to give it a thinner texture which would also probably work. I doubt it is a chemical reaction, but the recipe would help.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help. I have edited my post to link to my Evernote copy of the recipe.

Comment: I suspect that part of the issue is that yoghurt is acidic.  See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/13327/67