# Eggs in Pancakes, health hazard?

Tags: baking, pancakes, salmonella

I want to make pancakes. I have a powder mix that needs only milk to be ready.
However there is a note on the powder mix's box that says I can add an egg to the mix as well.

How safe is that? Are pancakes cooked enough to avoid risk of salmonella?

Comment: Even though I answered, I'm honestly a bit confused by the question - are you under the impression that eggs are always dangerous to eat? Or that eggs in pancakes somehow aren't cooked? Have we told you what you need to know?

Comment: I thought pancakes are not cooked enough to kill off salmonella in eggs. Thanks

Comment: Can you rephrase the question to be clear that your wondering about egg being cooked when making pancakes, as it stands the question is very confusing even with the answer provided.

Comment: we're assuming they get eaten up, well, like hotcakes. If they sit around warm, the undercooked portion can get nasty: a chef I  know sent a dozen diners to the Dr. from a not-runny-one-bit quiche kept at blood temp 4hrs.

Comment: Not having eggs in pancakes is what's unusual and something I would be worried about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eggs are completely safe in cooked food, and pancakes are cooked. Pancakes made from scratch have egg in the batter too. As long as you don't drink the batter, or more realistically, leave an uncooked bit in the middle of the pancakes, you're totally safe.

(And of course, it doesn't take much to kill salmonella, and a mL of uncooked batter right in the middle of a pancake has *ridiculously* small odds of getting you sick even if it's somehow still cold, but if you're trying to play by all the rules, then you should make sure they're fully cooked - you probably want that anyway.)

Answer (score 7):

This isn't really a question about pancakes, it's about the risk of getting salmonella poisoning from eggs.

As to the likelihood of eggs having salmonella, you could start here:

[Is it safe to eat raw eggs?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2957/is-it-safe-to-eat-raw-eggs)

[How does salmonella get into eggs?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5702/how-does-salmonella-get-into-eggs)

In any case, since you're going to be cooking the pancakes, you should be fine.  If you *really* want to be sure they're safe, you could check the temperature of your pancakes once they're done.  [Salmonella bacteria can be killed by a temperature of 160 F](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/Fact_Sheets/Salmonella_Questions_&_Answers/index.asp#9), so that's what you want to look for.

Comment: I don't think the OP intends to eat the batter raw.

Comment: Sorry, between the mistake I made in formatting and the funny wording I banged out at first, it wasn't clear.  Hopefully it's more obvious now that I was only including the mention of raw eggs for completeness.

Comment: Ah, cool. I think you'd have a lot of trouble trying to check the internal temperature of a pancake with a thermometer - and like you say, there's really no need to worry if they're cooked through.

Answer (score 1):

When using raw eggs to go with the Pancake. I suggest you use the pasteurized shell egg. That's the safest egg. 
Pasteurized eggs kill bacteria right through the center of the yolk and destroy all the bacteria and you don't have any risk.

Comment: 0 risk? Can you cite a source that shows that?

Comment: Pancakes are cooked. You don't need any special kind of eggs to make them safe.